# If the codomain of the following function is R , is the function surjective?

Tags: functions

The function given to me was $f(x)= ln|ln(x-[x])|$

This is how I attempted it :-

The given function is also the same as $ln|ln\{x\}|$
Now , as $\{x\}<1$, therefore $ln\{x\}$ will take all possible negative values. It’s absolute value will this give us the all possible positive numbers. Therefore the domain $ln|ln\{x\}|$ will have all positive numbers and this will give us all the real numbers. So it’s surjective.

Is my reasoning correct ? If I am mistaken , kindly point it out. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Jean thank you for confirming :)

Comment: Gioven $x\in\Bbb R$, consider $x=e^{-e^y}+42$

Comment: @Hagen I’m sorry but could you please explain what you mean ?